# Android: Perform Small Action When App Leaves Foreground

Tags: java, android

I am building a timer application and would like to pause it whenever the user removes the app from the foreground (such as via the Back or Home buttons). What would be the easiest way to do this? I'm thinking onStop() would be, but I have never done this before, so I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by overriding [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) (or [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) if you only want user actions.)

Comment: Isn't onPause() for when part of the application is still visible on the screen? My application will not be visible.

Comment: `onPause()` is the only method guaranteed to be called, unlike `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`. That phrase " no longer visible to the user" is a little odd since `onPause()` is "called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background". I'm having trouble thinking of a common instance when `onPause()` has been called but you can still see the layout...

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly for the home button. However, I notice that the Back button seems to operate differently. It seems to me that pressing it immediately after entering the app actually serves to close the app entirely instead of just moving it to the background. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but the system can kill your app if it is low on memory.

Comment: So is onStop() called instead when the app is killed?

Comment: "Is this correct?" Yes, the Back button destroys the immediately by calling `onPause()`, `onStop()`, then `onDestroy()`. The Home button only calls `onPause()` and `onStop()`.